# How do I center an image inside a div given my code situation?

Tags: image, css, vertical-alignment, centering

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="/images/img.png" class="img_pic" />
    </div>
</div>

.box {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 73px;
    margin: 40px 42px 0 0;
    width: 269px;
}
.img_pic {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I want the image ("img_pic") to be centered vertically as well.  With what I have I can do it horizontally but not vertically.  I tried `vertical-align: middle;` but that didn't work and I tried `line-height: 73px` since the height of the box is `73px`.  I can't seem to figure a way out of this.

How can I center the image vertically while still retaining the horizontal centering?

Answer (score 2):

Don't make the image a block element. As an inline element you can center it as text. Then set the line height to the same as the box, and set vertical alignment on the image to `middle` to put it in the middle of the text line:

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 73px;
    margin: 40px 42px 0 0;
    width: 269px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 73px;
}
.img_pic {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AwgNy/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `vertical-align` block elements.

If you know the height of the image you could put an equal `top` and `bottom` `margin` on `.img_plc` or an equal `top` and `bottom` padding on `.box.'

As you've said it's variable height, then you can use [display: table-cell](http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table) for .box with `vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions of the image you can do it in the css and either use margin to push it down:

```
margin-top:/*(box height / 2) - (image height / 2)*/;
```

or use relative and absolute positioning:

```
.box
{
    position:relative;
    /*other code*/
}

.image_pic
{
    position:absolute;
    top:/*(box height / 2) - (image height / 2)*/;
}
```

If you cannot guarantee the dimensions of the image then you should use javascript/jQuery to get the image height and use the same formula as above for working out the offset. Then still using javascript/jQuery, edit the css for the image to set the offset for `margin-top` or `top`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use This CSS **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/zBz5t/)**

```
.box {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 73px;
    margin: 40px 42px 0 0;
    width: 269px;
    position:relative
}
.img_pic {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:auto
}
```